# Change Model's column attribute

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an already migrated Django model, which was created this way:

```
    operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Victim',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=200)),
            ('instagram', models.CharField(max_length=254)),
            ('old_password', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)),
            ('new_password', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

But now, I want to make email and instagram attribute `Blank=True`, but password fields make `Blank=False`.

What is the easiest way to do this: delete and recreate the model (data is not important) or is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: I find it rather odd that you store an `old_password`, and `new_password` in a model. This are probably fields in a *form*, not in the model (furthermore normally passwords should be hashed).

Comment: Don't touch migrations. Change your fields in models.py to make blank=True/False. run makemigrations, then migrate. no data will be lost from database

Comment: if u want really to create same model without updating,easier way just delete model apply makemigration command and migrate. now it will drop table. create new model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still change your models and run `manage.py makemigrations`. It will create another migration to execute the required SQL statements to alter your database schema when running `manage.py migrate`. This is the role of migrations.